# Multiple files with no header to merge with one header

Tags: cat, merge

I have 58 files named as xaa.csv to xcf.csv, none of them have headers. I have a separate file with the header. How can I merge the files with the header and have 59 outputs merged?

For example:

```
input xaa.csv xab.csv ..... xcf.csv
output
xaa + header.csv xab + header.csv....
```

Comment: It seems that DopeGhoti created a solution that results in 59 files, each with a header; did you want one file with (header + 58 inputs), or 59 files with (header + 1 input) ?

Comment: No, I wanted what dopeghoti said! Thank you, though! :)

Comment: perfect; don't forget to accept their answer, then!

Comment: Hello Jeff, it's my first post here. How do I do it? Saying it was useful?

Comment: there should be a checkmark next to the answer; clicking it will make it turn green - that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in ???.csv; do
   cat header.csv "$file" > "joined-$file"
done
```

Comment: I think he wants header after the contents.

Comment: I want header before the contents in each file

Comment: The provided command will put the header ahead of the data; I figured that was what you wanted, or  you would have called it a footer.

Comment: I wrote what you proposed DopeGhoti and saved as an .sh but it didn't seem to work. However, a friends proposed this:
ls -l x*.csv | awk -F' ' '{body = $9; system("cat header.csv  " body " > " body ".new")}' and it worked quite well!

Answer (score 1):

With brace expansion:

```
cat header.csv x{a..b}{a..z}.csv xc{a..f}.csv > merged-file
```

This puts the contents of header.csv, followed by the contents of each of the x??.csv files into one merged-file.